# Box shadow rendering issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, box-shadow

I am currently working on a site which has an design where the main 'welcoming text' contains more than one line (as it is a short introduction about a product). This has an background of a transparant (0.7) white (`rgba(255,255,255,0.7)` with multiline padding. Yes, multiline padding I am saying. What that means, is that every line of text has top, bottom, left and right padding, background color and also a small transparent space between the lines.

To accomplish this, I used a box-shadow with an horizontal offset to simulate the left and right padding on each line. This does work on all browsers except Internet Explorer. As we want to have site working on all browsers I tried fixing this problem for a while now and I almost have come to the conclusion that this is just an internet explorer issue.

I used Geoff Muskett his example (http://geoffmuskett.com/text-with-background-padding-on-the-end-of-each-line-and-a-gap-between-lines/) and it does work as excepted except IE.

The problem is that when I open the page in IE, the box-shadows seems to be rendered somewhat blurry even though I set the blur to 0 pixels. (or just not added it, both did not work).

Even the code from Geoff his example does not work:

**HTML**

```
<h2><span>Could you benefit from having Alfi in your home?</span></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 { 
   line-height: 1.8em; 
   font-size: 1.7em;   
   display: inline; 
}  
h2 span { 
   padding: 0.2em; 
   box-shadow: 0.2em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7), -0.2em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7);    
   background-color: #fff; 
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
}
```

Is there anybody here that knows this issue and knows if there is a solution to this that is not very hacky (not preferred)?

IE 11.0.9600.17905

---

## EDIT

3 August 2015 09:32

I have been investigating this issue this weekend and found some posts of people having exactly the same issue as I am currently having. This seems to be a rendering bug in IE. See: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810756/ie-11-gap-between-element-background-and-its-box-shadow

Also in another StackOverflow post, someone by the name of @nickmorss says using the `box-shadow` to accomplish the multiline padded text is not working in IE11 and FF34+. It could be fixed in FF using `box-decoration-break: clone;` but this does not work at my side.

I think this is something not fixable in CSS by myself as this may be just a narly bug.

Comment: IE11 11.0.9600.17905

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked in IE11

```css
body{
    background-color: blue;
    
}
h2 { 
   
   line-height: 1.8em; 
   font-size: 1.7em;   
   display: inline; 
}  
h2 span { 
   padding: 0.2em; 
   box-shadow: 0.2em 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255,0.7), -0.2em 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7);    
   background-color: #fff; 
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Could you benefit from having Alfi in your home? Making this text a little longer so that it wraps on stackoverflow</span></h2>
```

So I'm thinking that maybe your site is perhaps in quirks mode, or using a different rendering mode other than IE11.

Confirm that you are running in IE11 mode by pressing F12 and going to the emulation tab. Are you in the right document mode. If not you will have to fix your site to ensure it's using the right document mode.

Please note, that in the comments of that blog post it does mention it doesn't work in Firefox, but someone has post code that does.
[image]

Comment: That does not work in IE11 here. Document is on default Edge, browserprofile is Desktop, characterset of the user agent is on default.

Comment: Added image of the rendering in Chrome and IE11 to my answer. Is this different from what you see or have I miss understood the problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I not want. At your example (image) you have no padding on the left and right on the second line of text ('your home? Making this text a little'. I want the padding on each line on the left and right and also keep it responsive, so forcing (hardcoding) three spans is not a solution.

Comment: So this isn't working in Chrome or IE. The question implied this was an IE issue only. In my image You have chrome on the left and IE on the right, rendering the code the same.

Comment: Ahhh OK I fixed the RGBA issue with the original code posting. Now I see what you mean.

Comment: I'm finding that solid colours look less noticeable than using ones with alpha transparency. A white solid colour on the right colour background is hardly noticeable (which is why Geoff Muskett probably assumed it worked)

Comment: I found out this seems to be a bug. See my edit in the openings post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll solve it but try declaring your rgba values as `rgba(255,255,255,0.7)` I've not seen hex values used within rgba before and this may be confusing IE

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake I already solved. I will change that to the correct rgba value.